# 1 not equal to 0 but the code says equal in c

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

This code prints both "equal" and "1 0".

Why is this happening even though `1 != 0` ?

```
if(2/2 == 2/2.0) 
    printf("equal \n");

printf("%d  %d", 2/2, 2/2.0);
```

Comment: Undefined behavior, you can't use `%d` for a double

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/694576

Answer (score 5):

The result of `2/2.0` is of type *double*. But you are using `%d` to print it, which is *undefined behaviour*. Use `%lf` instead to print a *double*. That's why you get `0` which is a possible result of invoking undefined behaviour.